# Subclass parameterization issue

Tags: java, javafx, subclass

So in class Test I'm creating observableLists of type A, where A has subclasses B and C. One list is for objects of each subclass. However, I'm receiving the following error:

```
The method foo(ObservableList<A>) in the type is not applicable for the arguments (ObservableList<B>).
```

Why is this happening? Since B is a subclass of A, shouldn't this work?

Other notes:

A, B, and C are in a different package than Test.

Comment: `ObservableList<A>` is *not* the supertype of `ObservableList<B>`. The explanation involves bounded type parameters. See tutorial on [Generics, Inheritance, and Subtypes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This shouldn't work. Let's use concrete examples.

`foo(List<Number>)` does not accept `List<Double>`. If you expect a `List<Number>` you expect to be able to add `Number`s to it. You can't add any `Number` to a `List<Double>`, now can you?

Consider the following possible implementation - pretend it allowed us to compile this:

```
void foo(List<Number> list) {
   /// all lists have to have a 42
   list.add(new Integer("42"));
}

// later
List<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();
// oh man, we need to foo this list!
foo(list); // kaboom! when we add the integer to the double list!!
```

Answer (score 0):

Since B is subclass of A, B may have more properties than A. That is the reason for the mismatch.

Comment: This answer doesn't make sense - if you expected A, and got a B, you would be able to do all the things to that B that you could to the A. The problem is because it's a container of B's, you can't add a C to it, which you could if it were a collection of A's.

Comment: I think I havent expressed it well. But we are on the same page.